# How can I disable XCode BITCODE within a CMake project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, bitcode

I am building a medium size project that uses CMake for project generation. On the XCode 7+ the ENABLE_BITCODE option is set to "Yes" by default. I would like to set that to "No" by default in my generated XCode projects.

I have tried adding "-fno-embed-bitcode" and "-fno-embed-bitcode-marker" to my CMAKE_C_FLAGS but this had no effect.

Answer (score 15):

Turns out I did not search enough. You can do this by calling:

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_BITCODE "NO")
```

from your CMake project.